# Java Hiding/Showing JTextFields dependant on value of a combobox

Tags: java, combobox

I can grasp the concepts but how the code (packages) interact with each other is quite a challenge for me to learn.

Enough of that, onto my question:

I want to `.setVisible()` a `JTextField` depending on a value which is being set in a combobox. Should I (or another user for that matter) set the value in the combobox to "Hide" the `JTextField` should be set to `setVisible(false)`.

Here is my code:

```
/*
    JTextField Show Hide Example
    This java example shows how to show or hide JTextField
    using Java Swing JTextField class.
*/


import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JTextFieldShowHideExample extends JApplet{

    public void init(){

            //set flow layout for the applet
            this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            //create new JTextField
            JTextField field = new JTextField("JTextField Show Hide Example", 20);
            field.setVisible(true);
            add(field);

            String[] choiceShowHide =  
                { "" + "Show","Hide"
                };
            final JComboBox<String> cbchoiceShowHide = new JComboBox<String>(choiceShowHide);
            cbchoiceShowHide.setVisible(true);
            add(cbchoiceShowHide);
    }
}
```

I suspect that I need to use an `if` statement something among the line of

```
 if (choiceShowHide == 'hide') {
     set field.setVisible(false);
  }
```

I am not certain if my train of thought is correct here.

Anybody who can advise me on how to achieve my ulimate goal here? (Until I have learnt more of Java and set higher, more ultimate goals for myself).

Comment: You need a selection Listener on the combo box.
I suggest looking at the javadocs at oracle for comboBox, it will lead you to the tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your `JComboBox` to change the visibility of `JTextField` i.e perform some event upon some action that is performed onto it which is selection of an Item from the combo box(in this case), you need to use something called as an ActionListener. 
I won't be going to the depths of this interface and merely scratch the surface saying that this interface contains a public abstract `actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg)` method that takes an `ActionEvent` argument.

Considering that you are a beginner, you don't need to know all the details of this class. Only thing you need to know is, you need to register an ActionListener for the component which you want some action to perform(JComboBox in your case) using the `addActionListener(ActionListener arg)` on the calling object with a `.` operator.

public class JTextFieldShowHideExample extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

```
JComboBox<String> cbchoiceShowHide;
JTextField field;
public void init(){

        //set flow layout for the applet
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //create new JTextField
        field = new JTextField("JTextField Show Hide Example", 20);
        field.setVisible(true);
        add(field);

        String[] choiceShowHide =  
            { "" + "Show","Hide"
            };
        cbchoiceShowHide = new JComboBox<String>(choiceShowHide);
        cbchoiceShowHide.setVisible(true);
        add(cbchoiceShowHide);
        cbchoiceShowHide.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(cbchoiceShowHide.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("show"))
        field.setVisible(true);
    else
        field.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

In your previous code, you had created `cbchoiceShowHide` and `field` as a local variable, and hence you won't be able to use it outside the `init()` unless you declare it as an instance variable, which is exactly what i have done in this case.

For you understanding,
`cbchoiceShowHide.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("show")`
this is the magical line that makes the code working. the `getSelectedItem()` will return an object instance representing the select item from the combo box, which we convert to string using the famous `toString()` and then compare it for the String 'Show' and set the field's visibility to true for the same.

Upvote and Select the answer if this helps:-)

Comment: Very much appreciated for the explanation! That did the job indeed. Onwards I go; learning more :)

Comment: All d Best - Also upvote the answer for handful number of good reasons :-)

Comment: I did upvote? (The arrow upward is the one for upvoting, If I am not mistaken). If that is not done, dreadfully sorry for that. I shall re-read the instructions and upvote your answer (y)

Comment: Oopsie!! Your reputation should be at least 15, only then your up votes will be publicly visible, Neverminf though :D